# python: geometric brownian motion simulation

Tags: python, random, simulation

A basic simulation of GBM doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong? The following code always outputs values less than 1e-20, instead of something distributed randomly around 1.0:

```
import math
import random

p = 1
dt = 1
mu = 0
sigma = 1
for k in range(100):
    p *= math.exp((mu - sigma * sigma / 2) * dt +
         sigma * random.normalvariate(0, dt * dt))
print(p)
```

I'm running:

ActivePython 3.1.2.3 (ActiveState Software Inc.) based on
Python 3.1.2 (r312:79147, Mar 22 2010, 12:30:45) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on
win32

My OS is Windows 7 Professional on i7-930 CPU (64-bit).

I'd be happy to run any other tests on my machine to isolate the problem.

Comment: What Python version are you running? Some machine info would be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer. There is no problem with the code. It's just that the resulting lognormal distribution has enormous scale parameter = 1 *  sqrt(100) = 10. With scale of 10, the skewness is insane.

Thus, even though the mean of the distribution is 1.0, it will take me billions of iterations (if not ***billions of billions***) to see a single number greater than 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

Seems fine:

```
import math
import random

def compute():
    p = 1
    dt = 1
    mu = 0
    sigma = 1
    for k in range(100):
        p *= math.exp((mu - sigma * sigma / 2) * dt +
                      sigma * random.normalvariate(0, dt * dt))
    return p

print [compute() for x in range(20)]
```

gives:

```
[118.85952235362008, 7.3312246638859059e-14, 29.509674994408684, 1.8720575806397408, 1.5882398997219834e-05, 2967.524471541024, 0.0031130343677571093, 19942.669293314699, 0.00011878818261757498, 5382.80288111769, 0.22867624175360118, 0.028535167622775418, 12.6324011631628, 20.604456159054738, 0.0034504567371058613, 6.5804828930878056e-06, 6398.0493448486704, 0.0014978345496292245, 721546.38343724841, 1285.546939393781]
```

This is using python 2.6.1

Comment: Using ActiveState Python 3.1.2.3 on x64 Windows 7, I'm getting: 2.88084588316e-26
1.79846330571e-29
5.33216495039e-16
3.65633773649e-24
1.4585366594e-20
5.89100557394e-29
6.54803262332e-22
6.4358184422e-26
5.84172579131e-16
1.54534837363e-20
1.80941931541e-21
1.1932380739e-19
2.05849658827e-19
2.72778662212e-26
5.76789574386e-11
1.28691566317e-20
2.0417208905e-17
1.06184638238e-28
8.75599425267e-26
9.76030276598e-24

Answer (score 0):

Running the code in Python 2.6.6 gets reasonable answers, while running it in Python 3.1.2 gives the small numbers you describe. I think this is because in Python 2.x the division operator gives an integer result when dividing two integers, while in Python 3.x it gives a floating-point result in the same situation. Hence the divide-by-two in the calculation gives different results depending on what version.

To make it consistent, force the output of the division to an integer:

```
p *= math.exp(int(mu - sigma * sigma / 2)) * dt +
     sigma * random.normalvariate(0, dt * dt))
```

This makes the output the same in both 2.x and 3.x. A sample set of output on my machine is:

0.0243898032782, 6126.78299771, 0.00450839758621, 1.17316856812, 0.00479489258202, 4.88995369021e-06, 0.033957530608, 29.9492464423, 3.16953460691

This seems to be in the ballpark of what you are looking for.

Comment: But my sigma is 1. So `sigma*sigma / 2` would be equal to `0` in Python 2.6. That's certainly not what I want. I am following the standard GBM formula, and I would need to use float division to replicate it.

Answer (score 0):

Using float division (//) rather than integer division (/) in Python 3.1 works:

```
import math
import random

p = 1
dt = 1
mu = 0
sigma = 1
for k in range(100):
    p *= math.exp((mu - sigma * sigma // 2) * dt +
         sigma * random.normalvariate(0, dt * dt))
print(p)
```

On an example run, I got the following numbers:

0.0989269233704
2536660.91466
2146.09989782
0.502233504924
0.43052439984
14.1156450335

Comment: // is integer division, not float. I actually need float...