# Correlation between columns in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I'm pretty new to pandas, so I guess I'm doing something wrong -

I have a DataFrame:

```
     a     b
0  0.5  0.75
1  0.5  0.75
2  0.5  0.75
3  0.5  0.75
4  0.5  0.75
```

`df.corr()` gives me:

```
    a   b
a NaN NaN
b NaN NaN
```

but `np.correlate(df["a"], df["b"])` gives: `1.875`

Why is that? 
I want to have the correlation matrix for my DataFrame and thought that `corr()` does that (at least according to the documentation). Why does it return `NaN`?

What's the correct way to calculate?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 73, accepted):

[np.correlate](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.correlate.html) calculates the (unnormalized) [cross-correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation) between two 1-dimensional sequences:

```
z[k] = sum_n a[n] * conj(v[n+k])
```

while [df.corr](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html) (by default) calculates the [Pearson correlation coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient#For_a_sample).

The correlation coefficient (if it exists) is always between -1 and 1 inclusive.
The cross-correlation is not bounded.

The formulas are somewhat related, but notice that in the cross-correlation formula (above) there is no subtraction of the means, and no division by the standard deviations which is part of the formula for Pearson correlation coefficient.

The fact that the standard deviation of `df['a']` and `df['b']` is zero is what causes `df.corr` to be NaN everywhere.

---

From the comment below, it sounds like you are looking for [Beta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_%28finance%29). It is related to Pearson's correlation coefficient, but instead of dividing by the product of standard deviations:

[image]

you divide by a variance:

[image]

---

You can compute `Beta` using [np.cov](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cov.html)

```
cov = np.cov(a, b)
beta = cov[1, 0] / cov[0, 0]
```

---

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed(100)


def geometric_brownian_motion(T=1, N=100, mu=0.1, sigma=0.01, S0=20):
    """
    http://stackoverflow.com/a/13203189/190597 (unutbu)
    """
    dt = float(T) / N
    t = np.linspace(0, T, N)
    W = np.random.standard_normal(size=N)
    W = np.cumsum(W) * np.sqrt(dt)  # standard brownian motion ###
    X = (mu - 0.5 * sigma ** 2) * t + sigma * W
    S = S0 * np.exp(X)  # geometric brownian motion ###
    return S

N = 10 ** 6
a = geometric_brownian_motion(T=1, mu=0.1, sigma=0.01, N=N)
b = geometric_brownian_motion(T=1, mu=0.2, sigma=0.01, N=N)

cov = np.cov(a, b)
print(cov)
# [[ 0.38234755  0.80525967]
#  [ 0.80525967  1.73517501]]
beta = cov[1, 0] / cov[0, 0]
print(beta)
# 2.10609347015

plt.plot(a)
plt.plot(b)
plt.show()
```

[image]

The ratio of `mu`s is 2, and `beta` is ~2.1.

---

And you could also compute it with `df.corr`, though this is a much more round-about way of doing it (but it is nice to see there is consistency):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': a, 'b': b})
beta2 = (df.corr() * df['b'].std() * df['a'].std() / df['a'].var()).ix[0, 1]
print(beta2)
# 2.10609347015
assert np.allclose(beta, beta2)
```

Comment: Thanks!

So in case my "a" and "b" are daily changes of prices and I want to measure how does "b" does with respect to "a" (meaning - if every time "a" goes up by 1% b goes up by 2% I'd expect to see 2.0, if "b" is always -0.5% I'd expect -0.5).
I guess the 'cross-correlation' is what I want, right?